# Figuring out a relation for queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I currently have a few models that either do or don't directly relate to a user.  `User` `Region` and `Location`.

`User` is related to `Location` through a ForeignKey `manager` and `Region` is related to `Location` through a ForeignKey `region`.

My question is what would be the correct queryset to show the relationship between the `User` and the `Region` for example if I were to return all the Regions that belonged to a certain user.

```
class Region(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class Location(models.Model):
    region = models.ForeignKey(Region, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I want to try and avoid having a direct relationship between `User` and `Region` if I can help it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the `user` variable is a `User` instance,

You can have a lookup like this:

```
 regions = Region.objects.filter(location__user=user)
```

Basically, for the reverse foreign key relationship in the queryset, you would use the lowercase modelname for the field lookup - `location` in this case.

If such a relationship does not exist, `regions.count()` would be `0`

Documentation of this feature is [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Another way of achieving this is,

```
regions = user.location_set.values('region') #or values_list - or however you want this
```

Comment: Add the prefetch_related also for reducing the queries (in the filter example :) )